# Highcharts issues in add like 1/10 on top of the column chart

Tags: json, highcharts

I am generate graph.[link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/XRr8M/2/ .Here i want show my total stack value is 1/10, 2/10, 5/10 like this on top of the column.But i am trying this.That code not shows like 1/10,2/10 ,it shows 0.00/10 like this.How can i display my total stackvalue/10 on the top of the column.So please give me the suggestions.

Here is my code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 50
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Top  Rating',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'testing',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'monthly Rating'
        },
        stackLabels: {

                enabled: true,
            formatter:function(){
               //  return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y  +'/10'
               return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y) + '/10'
            },
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
        }
    },
    plotOptions:{
         dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,

                    },
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color:'white',

                }
            }
            },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'RATING',
        data: [],
        id: 'dataseries'
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
        data: [{

            x: 0,
            text: 'Minimum Facilites Rating',
            title: 'Min'
        }, {

            x: 10,
            text: 'Maximum Facilites Rating',
            title: 'max'
        }],
        width: 30,
        showInLegend: false
    }]
    };

    //imitate AJAX:
   json = [{
       data: ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e', 'f', 'g','h','i', 'j', 'k','l']
   }, {
    data: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1]
   }];
    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
    options.series[0].data = json[1]['data'];

     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

     });
```

So please request to all of you give me idea how it is possible.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan Please help me on this query also

Comment: @Pawel Fus Please solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this.total not this.y inside formatter.

```
  return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total) + '/10'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XRr8M/7/

Comment: Thanks for your response.Its fine .Your code runs like 3.00/10 ,2.00/10,etc.But I need only 3/10,2/10,etc..only integer type not decimal point.So request to you how it is possible.

Comment: Set it is the numberFormat http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Highcharts.numberFormat by numer decimals parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response.but i have tried this numberformat convert from decimal to int like 3/10,2/10.but i am failed.So please tell me how it is convert from decimal to only integer number format.

Comment: Why you cannot numeberFormat? http://jsfiddle.net/XRr8M/12/ what is wrong with that?